# Exposing relationships in REST APIs (how does the user refer to objects?)

Tags: rest, web, api-design, hateoas

In my models I have `Event`s and `User`s. Each `Event` has a `leader` attribute that points to a `User`, however there isn't always a host necessarily, in which case host is null.

In my API:

`GET /users/` returns a list of all users

`GET /users/3/` returns user 3 info, `{"name": "John", "href": "/users/3/"}`

`GET /events/` returns a list of all events

`GET /events/2/host/` should return the user who is a host for event 2. (say this is user 3)

Should I return `{"href": "/users/3/"}`, simply a link to the User? Or the representation of the user itself, `{"name": "John", "href": "/users/3/"}`?

Lets say I go with the first option. How do I change the user?

`PUT /events/2/host/ json={"href": "/users/2/"}` - does this make sense? My server would then have to parse the endpoint to figure out which user id is the new host, and then assign that in the database. Seems a bit inelegant, but Flask has a way to parse the endpoint into the arguments. But is this the right way to do it?

Finally, in the `GET /events/2/` resource, I was thinking about having an attribute `"host":{"href": "/events/2/host/"}` in the representation. Does this make sense? And if there's no host, there would be no `href` attribute at all, just an empty dictionary assigned to `host`.

Answer (score 0):

To be short, I think that you should return the representation when getting, for example, host for an event and use the link when updating it. But the design remains up to you ;-)

Here are the different cases:

```
GET /events/2/host/
{"name": "John", "href": "/users/3/"}

PUT /events/2/host/
{"href": "/users/3/"}

DELETE /events/2/host/ (to set the host field to null)
```

I think that the OData v4 specification could give you some good ideas for your design. This link gives good insights about the way to handle entity relations with OData : http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/entity-relations-in-odata-v4.

Moreover with its query parameter `$expand`, OData allows to configure if you load the entity dependency. If the field `host` is for example defined, you will have the content of the referenced entity, if not, only the reference.

OData also provides a way to get the reference for a dependency with the suffix `$ref`.

Another link could also give you some ideas: http://templth.wordpress.com/2014/12/15/designing-a-web-api/.

Hope it helps you.
Thierry